# I was trying to make a random forest Ai model to predict the retention of an employee in a company thats when i got this error, Exception in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scikit-learn, random-forest

code related to it:

```
    for sh in xlrd.open_workbook(myPath).sheets():
        popp = findCell(sh, searchedValue)
        test_str = popp
        print(popp)
        index_list = [1]
        new_str = [test_str[i] for i in index_list]
        rownum = "".join(new_str)

        rownum = int(rownum)
        for roww in ws.iter_rows(min_row=rownum, min_col=3, max_row=rownum, max_col=3):
            for cell in roww:
                total_hours_worked = cell.value
            print()
        for rowww in ws.iter_rows(min_row=rownum, min_col=4, max_row=rownum, max_col=4):
            for cell in rowww:
                leaves_taken = cell.value
            print()

    Prediction_result = ('  Predicted Result: ', forest.predict([[total_hours_worked, leaves_taken]]))
```

error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\parth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Parth/ChurnPrediciton/not so accurate model/error.py", line 75, in values
    Prediction_result = ('  Predicted Result: ', forest.predict([[total_hours_worked, leaves_taken]]))
  File "C:\Parth\ChurnPrediciton\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py", line 612, in predict
    proba = self.predict_proba(X)
  File "C:\Parth\ChurnPrediciton\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py", line 656, in predict_proba
    X = self._validate_X_predict(X)
  File "C:\Parth\ChurnPrediciton\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py", line 412, in _validate_X_predict
    return self.estimators_[0]._validate_X_predict(X, check_input=True)
  File "C:\Parth\ChurnPrediciton\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py", line 380, in _validate_X_predict
    X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csr")
  File "C:\Parth\ChurnPrediciton\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 531, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\parth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 83, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Total Working Hours'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I made this model a few days ago and it was working perfectly fine, it was giving the proper output and all but suddenly it stopped working. And I'm not able to understand why it is happening

Answer (score 0):

So, in my case the error was in the data itself, some of the data was in format of a float datatype so it was not able to convert it into a string. So I went into my excel sheet and csv files and changed the values, and everything's working perfectly now